# SQL Server: using IF with as in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MY_STORED_PROCEDURE]
AS
BEGIN  
SELECT UserSituation,UserName

//Question is here
 IF ( UserSituation==1) AS UserSituation_True
 IF ( UserSituation==0) AS UserSituation_False

FROM User
```

I want to match `UserSituation`.

- If `UserSituation` is **1**, I want to change it is name as `UserSituation_True`
- If `UserSituation` is **0** , I want to change it is name as `UserSituation_False`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I undestood. You want that id situation is one then the username column has the value 'UserSituation_True' and if 0 the value should be 'UserSituation_False'?! I'm I right?

Comment: if value is 1 true if value is 0 false there is no null thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UserSituation, UserName, Case WHEN UserSituation = 0 THEN 'FALSE' WHEN UserSituation = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE '?' END FROM User
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little hard to interpret.

And your select statements needs from clauses, and these should also be included in the if statement.
And most of your question could be answered by a little search:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Is it change column name then:

IF ( UserSituation==1)
    BEGIN
        select UserName, UserSituation_True = 1
    END 
    IF ( UserSituation==0)
    BEGIN
        select UserName, UserSituation_FALSE = 0
    END

Is it change value of userSituation:
 IF ( UserSituation==1)
    BEGIN
        select UserName, UserSituation = TRUE
    END 
    IF ( UserSituation==0)
    BEGIN
        select UserName, UserSituation = FALSE
    END